# get values from string and copy the values to pojo properties : java

Tags: java, regex, string, spring-mvc, pojo

I have a string containing this values :

```
String verifyPaymentDetails = "{
2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}, 
6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}
}"
```

and I want to extract the values from the above string and store them like the following :

key would be `2298597` and values for the key `mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL`

```
Map<String,Item> tag = new HashMap<String,VerifyPaymentRO>();
```

and this is what is my `VerifyPaymentRO`

```
public class VerifyPaymentRO {
private String mihpayid;
private String request_id;
private String bank_ref_num;
private String amt;
private String disc;
private String mode;
private String PG_TYPE;
private String card_no;
private String name_on_card;
private String udf2;
private String addedon;
private String status;
private String unmappedstatus;
private String Merchant_UTR;
private String Settled_At;

public String getMihpayid() {
    return mihpayid;
}
public void setMihpayid(String mihpayid) {
    this.mihpayid = mihpayid;
}
public String getRequest_id() {
    return request_id;
}
public void setRequest_id(String request_id) {
    this.request_id = request_id;
}
public String getBank_ref_num() {
    return bank_ref_num;
}
public void setBank_ref_num(String bank_ref_num) {
    this.bank_ref_num = bank_ref_num;
}
public String getAmt() {
    return amt;
}
public void setAmt(String amt) {
    this.amt = amt;
}
public String getDisc() {
    return disc;
}
public void setDisc(String disc) {
    this.disc = disc;
}
public String getMode() {
    return mode;
}
public void setMode(String mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
}
public String getPG_TYPE() {
    return PG_TYPE;
}
public void setPG_TYPE(String pG_TYPE) {
    PG_TYPE = pG_TYPE;
}
public String getCard_no() {
    return card_no;
}
public void setCard_no(String card_no) {
    this.card_no = card_no;
}
public String getName_on_card() {
    return name_on_card;
}
public void setName_on_card(String name_on_card) {
    this.name_on_card = name_on_card;
}
public String getUdf2() {
    return udf2;
}
public void setUdf2(String udf2) {
    this.udf2 = udf2;
}
public String getAddedon() {
    return addedon;
}
public void setAddedon(String addedon) {
    this.addedon = addedon;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public String getUnmappedstatus() {
    return unmappedstatus;
}
public void setUnmappedstatus(String unmappedstatus) {
    this.unmappedstatus = unmappedstatus;
}
public String getMerchant_UTR() {
    return Merchant_UTR;
}
public void setMerchant_UTR(String merchant_UTR) {
    Merchant_UTR = merchant_UTR;
}
public String getSettled_At() {
    return Settled_At;
}
public void setSettled_At(String settled_At) {
    Settled_At = settled_At;
}

}
```

so how do get the id from the string and values for the id and copy the values to POJO and store them like id and object in a HashMap?

if there is way for this in spring also fine

Comment: you are trying to deserialize an String into an object. if the String is defined by you would be better to use a common serialization like JSON or XML to perform these operations and automatize the process. anyway, your request can be performed using regex or even StringTokenizer, but is quite long... it is not related with Spring at all.

Comment: @logoff would you give me some sample please

Comment: If it was a json, it would have been all too simple! I think extracting each value and manually setting them is the only way to go.

Comment: the String is defined by you then?

Comment: @logoff it is not defined by me and is a response from a request(webservice), I am trying to put them into a map as I have described in the question

Comment: A response from a webservice is most likely going to be a json. You can just google, how to parse a json using gson, and you'll get a lot of hits.

Comment: @R.J from the string I gave is not json. calling webservice responds back in PHP serialized string by default and I have parsed it after parsing I am able to get the value I described in question

Comment: As I mentioned before, if its not a json, you'll manually have to parse your String to extract all the data and set them manually to your Pojo.

Comment: since it is not JSON, it would be difficult to parse it. anyway it can be done, obviously. the first thing I can say, read about serialization/deserialization (or marshalling/unmarshalling). and the second one is to kill the WS provider.

Comment: @R.J understood your points, I think I have follow what R.J suggested :). would you please help me to get id and values separate might be using regex. Thanks

Comment: @R.J I think you suggest this way : http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-set-property-value-of-a-bean/.

Comment: You don't need any Utils. Just use the setters to set the values of the pojo. If you're planning to unmarshall it using Spring somehow(I don't know how), Spring internally has a parameterized bean setter.

Comment: @R.J how can I separate the values from this `6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}` like `6503939` and `={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}`

Comment: Have a look at the `split` function of String class. You're going to need it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is not a JSON and you really need to do the hard work, I think the best solution is to use the combination of [Rojo](https://github.com/LittleLightCz/Rojo) and [BeanMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html) from commons-beanutils. I am also author of Rojo, so I would like to show how it could be used in this context. I wouldn't recommend direct regexp mapping by group due to dynamically changing number of pairs inside, so that's why I think the BeanMap could do a lot of work for us.

First let's update your bean with **id**, which will serve as a primary key:

```
public class VerifyPaymentRO {
    private String id;

    private String mihpayid;
    private String request_id;
    private String bank_ref_num;
    private String amt;
    private String disc;
    private String mode;
    private String PG_TYPE;
    private String card_no;
    private String name_on_card;
    private String udf2;
    private String addedon;
    private String status;
    private String unmappedstatus;
    private String Merchant_UTR;
    private String Settled_At;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMihpayid() {
        return mihpayid;
    }

    public void setMihpayid(String mihpayid) {
        this.mihpayid = mihpayid;
    }

    public String getRequest_id() {
        return request_id;
    }

    public void setRequest_id(String request_id) {
        this.request_id = request_id;
    }

    public String getBank_ref_num() {
        return bank_ref_num;
    }

    public void setBank_ref_num(String bank_ref_num) {
        this.bank_ref_num = bank_ref_num;
    }

    public String getAmt() {
        return amt;
    }

    public void setAmt(String amt) {
        this.amt = amt;
    }

    public String getDisc() {
        return disc;
    }

    public void setDisc(String disc) {
        this.disc = disc;
    }

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public void setMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public String getPG_TYPE() {
        return PG_TYPE;
    }

    public void setPG_TYPE(String PG_TYPE) {
        this.PG_TYPE = PG_TYPE;
    }

    public String getCard_no() {
        return card_no;
    }

    public void setCard_no(String card_no) {
        this.card_no = card_no;
    }

    public String getName_on_card() {
        return name_on_card;
    }

    public void setName_on_card(String name_on_card) {
        this.name_on_card = name_on_card;
    }

    public String getUdf2() {
        return udf2;
    }

    public void setUdf2(String udf2) {
        this.udf2 = udf2;
    }

    public String getAddedon() {
        return addedon;
    }

    public void setAddedon(String addedon) {
        this.addedon = addedon;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getUnmappedstatus() {
        return unmappedstatus;
    }

    public void setUnmappedstatus(String unmappedstatus) {
        this.unmappedstatus = unmappedstatus;
    }

    public String getMerchant_UTR() {
        return Merchant_UTR;
    }

    public void setMerchant_UTR(String merchant_UTR) {
        Merchant_UTR = merchant_UTR;
    }

    public String getSettled_At() {
        return Settled_At;
    }

    public void setSettled_At(String settled_At) {
        Settled_At = settled_At;
    }
}
```

Now the working example could be as follows:

```
public class VerifyPaymentExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String verifyPaymentDetails = "{" +
                "2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}," +
                "6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}" +
                "}";

        Map<String, VerifyPaymentRO> result = Rojo.asMap("(\\d+)=\\{(.+?)\\}", verifyPaymentDetails)
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> toBean(e))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(VerifyPaymentRO::getId, Function.identity()));

    }

    public static VerifyPaymentRO toBean(Map.Entry<String,String> entry) {
        VerifyPaymentRO bean = new VerifyPaymentRO();
        bean.setId(entry.getKey());

        BeanMap beanMap = new BeanMap(bean);
        Rojo.asMap("(\\w.+?)=([^,]+)", entry.getValue())
            .forEach( (key, value) -> {
                //Some additional mapping is required due to non-standard naming
                if ("Settled_At".equals(key)) {
                    beanMap.put("settled_At", value);
                } else if ("Merchant_UTR".equals(key)) {
                    beanMap.put("merchant_UTR", value);
                } else {
                    beanMap.put(key, value);
                }
        });

        return bean;
    }
}
```

If you run the code and look into **result**, you should have exactly what you want.